# Сгруппировать данные по 15 минут

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица ПРОДАЖИ (Время datetime, Сумма Float)

Как посчитать общую сумму и кол-во на каждые 15 минут за сутки?

Чтобы получилось так

Время                 Количетво              Сумма
(01:30:00-01:45:00)     5                  123456
(01:45:00-02:00:00)     10                 235000
(02:00:00-02:15:00)     15                 535000

Comment: можно сгенерировать таблицу с нужными интервалами и приджойнить, можно из времени вычислить номер интервала `mod 15` и прогруппировать по нему. а вы как пробовали7

Comment: у меня была только идея с Case и перечислением

Comment: А как  из времени вычислить номер интервала mod 15 ?

Comment: взять из даты часы, умножить на 4, прибавить минуты, все это разделить на 15 нацело.

Comment: или взять искомую дату во временем `00:00`, вычислить разницу с нужной датой в минутах,  и снова разделить на 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея такая:

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Время) DIV (15 * 60)) * 15 * 60) as every15min, SUM(Сумма) as total 
FROM ПРОДАЖИ
GROUP BY every15min
ORDER BY every15min
```

Такой запрос округлит каждую дату-время до ближайшей кратной 15 минутам и сгруппирует уже по этому округленному дате-времени.

Comment: Благодарю!
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64)   Apr 27 2017 17:36:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)